# How do you programatically call an ashx file from dot.net?

Tags: c#, .net, ashx

I have been provided with an ashx "service" that returns an image. I'm new to ashx files - so don't know how to handle it.

I need to stream the image into a byte[] so I can copy it somewhere else. How do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried?  Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

Comment: Well, if they set the response headers correctly you should be able to just type the url in the browser and you should see the image. Or you need to do this programmatically?

Comment: Helpful hint: ask yourself "how will the .ashx file be called at all?" From a HTML page?

Comment: Yes - need to do it programatically. Should have mentioned!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [WebClient.DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddata%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) pointing to asxh.

So let me give you a sample. Let's say you have image located on asp.net page, like this:

```
<img src="http://someServer/someSite/MyHandler.ashx?id=myId"/>
```

In this case you can use following code:

```
        using (System.Net.WebClient wclient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            byte[] data = wclient.DownloadData(
                "http://someServer/someSite/MyHandler.ashx?id=myId");  
        }
```

Alternatively you can use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)